# Relationship between a diagonalisable matrix and the change of basis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, diagonalization, change-of-basis

With reference to I.N. Herstein Topics in Algebra theorem 6.3.2, it states that if $V$ a n-dimensional vector space over field $F$, and the linear transformation $T$ has the matrix $m_1(T)$ has the basis $v_1, ..., v_n$ and the matrix $m_2(T)$ in the basis of $w_1,...,w_n$, then there is a matrix C such that $m_2(T)=Cm_1(T)C^{-1}$. This is oddly similar to the diagonalisation of a matrix where $A=PDP^{-1}$. In this case, I know that the matrix $D$ is the matrix of eigenvalues of $A$, which is in the basis of $v_1, v_2, v_3$, the corresponding eigenvectors of $A$, and this is identical to the definition of $m_1(T)$ in the theorem.

I would like to show that $P$, the matrix of eigenvectors, satisfy the matrix $C$ in the theorem, that maps $v_1, ..., v_n$ to  $w_1,...,w_n$ which I am not sure how, since I do not know which basis $A$ is in.

Comment: If $A$ is the matrix of the transformation with respect to some basis, then the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors of the transformation with respect to the same basis.

Comment: Try the standard basis for the $v_i$ and the basis of eigenvectors for the $w_i$.

Comment: @angryavian should'nt the columns of $P$ be with respect to $D$ instead?

Comment: @TedShifrin $v_i$ should be with respect to any basis and not just the standard one right?

Comment: With respect to $D$ means nothing. When you write the matrix $A$, it represents a linear transformation. With respect to what basis?

Comment: My bad, I am refering to the columns of $P$ should be with respect to the same basis as that of matrix $D$, which is the basis of eigenvectors

Comment: A is with respect to any basis, since the eigenvectors of A is independent of the basis of A. Am I right?

Comment: @lel Do you want to show that if a matrix $A=PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, then there exists an invertible linear map $T : V\to V$ such that $M(T)=P$?

Comment: I know that there are exist such a $T$, and thus there will be a $M(T)=P$ that diagonalises $A$. What I am uncertain is why $M(T)$ is the matrix of eigenvectors and how does it map $v_i$ to $w_i$ since the basis of matrix A is unknown